# Filtering for specific attribute of a child

Tags: jquery, filter

I'm trying to find a child with this exact background color in a nav_list ul.

All `<li>` items are created dynamically; the `alert()` gives me `undefined`, what am I doing wrong?

```
var matching = $('.nav_list li').filter(function(){
                  return $(this).attr('background-color') == "rgb(72, 76, 111)"
               });
alert(matching.attr("class"));
```

Comment: Does the `matching` jQuery object contain any elements? Are you running the code *after* you've appended/inserted the dynamically-added `<li>` elements?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - you're looking for an html attribute, but `background-color` is a *css* attribute.

Comment: And then, even if it did find any elements, you're running `attr()` on a collection

Comment: @freedomn-m: A CSS *property*. CSS never calls them attributes for a reason. (Though that doesn't help the confusion with *DOM* properties.)

Comment: @david 
Yes `ul` elements are appended with "class" attributes and a `.length > 0` check is performed , before `filter() ` method is invoked
@freedomn
There will always be only one element with this `background-color` in the list, so wouldn't `filter()` return only one?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `.addClass("selected")` to mark those `<li>`'s that are clicked by the user